# How can I get the value of a select element in MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a form which includes a few input elements and a few select elements. The point is that for the input elements I provide them a name attribute and later use it in my controller to get their value. But I don't know how can I get the value of a select element, and give it to the controller. Here is just a small snippet from my form:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="state">Price range</label>
                <select name="price" class="form-control">
                    <option>$ 175,000 - $ 200,000</option>
                    <option>$ 200,000 - $ 250,000</option>
                    <option>$ 250,000 - $ 300,000</option>
                    <option>$ 300,000 - $ 350,000</option>
                    <option>$ 350,000 - $ 400,000</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="hear">What interests you?</label>
                <input type="text" name="interests" class="form-control" id="inputHear" placeholder="What interests you? ">
            </div>
```

Then, in my controller I have something like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Contact(..., string interests = "")
    {
         ...
    }
```

Can someone tell me how can I get the selected value from my select element?

Comment: `Request("price")` ??

Comment: How do you plan on sending info back to the server side?  You can form post, or do various forms of Ajax calls, etc.

Comment: @NeilN I have `@using (Html.BeginForm....)` defined, I just put this part of the code, while I don't know how can I get the value of the selected item.

Comment: @RobertRozas can you tell more about it?

Comment: @ett are you clicking a submit button?  If so the values should be bound the action methods parameters, assuming the names match up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text you can actually see is for the user, the value you are actually sending should be the contents of the value attribute on each option tag:

```
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="state">Price range</label>
            <select name="price" class="form-control">
                <option value="175,000 - 200,000">$ 175,000 - $ 200,000</option>
                <option value="200,000 - 250,000">$ 200,000 - $ 250,000</option>
                <option value="250,000 - 300,000">$ 250,000 - $ 300,000</option>
                <option value="300,000 - 350,000">$ 300,000 - $ 350,000</option>
                <option value="350,000 - 400,000">$ 350,000 - $ 400,000</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="hear">What interests you?</label>
            <input type="text" name="interests" class="form-control" id="inputHear" placeholder="What interests you? ">
        </div>
```

And then in your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Contact(string price, string interests = "")
{
     ...
}
```